# How can I create full page table with varying column widths?

Tags: tables

Concretely, this is what I want to do as described in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCcYA.jpg). Create two columns, one of larger width and spanning the whole page. I understand there is multicolumn but I can't seem to make it use.

Comment: Does this table span multiple pages?

Comment: @HarishKumar, Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible suggestion where `longtable` package is used. The varying length of each column `0.3\textwidth` and `0.7\textwidth` can be changed, but must they be added up to `1\textwidth`.

**Edit:** To color the left column, `colortbl` and `xcolor` are used with `\columncolor{gray}` and `\cellcolor{gray}` commands.

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,lipsum,longtable,colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3em}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{longtable}{%
|>{\columncolor{gray}}p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
|p{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\cellcolor{gray}} A column} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{B column}\\ \hline
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,longtable,dcolumn}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3em}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{%
|p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
|p{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A column} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{B column}\\ \hline
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jesse thank you. One last question, is there a way, I can color the left column gray?

Comment: @Jesse thank you. One last question, is there a way, I can color the left column gray?

Comment: @user1343318 -- Please see my update.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thank you sir. Noted and corrected accordingly.