# Creating a table within a longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I have created a longtable by using information from the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165267/how-can-i-create-full-page-table-with-varying-column-widths/165272?noredirect=1#comment379524_165272). Now I want to create a table with two columns with 3 rows each within the right part of this long table. A pictorial representation is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TGbc.jpg). I tried to do use itemize but it fails to compile. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Please always post a complete (small)  document that shows the problem. You can nest itemize or tabular inside a longtable cell in a `p` column, so if it didn't compile you made an error that is impossible to guess.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the tabular into one of the cell, as said by David Carlisle: you can nest itemize or tabular inside a longtable cell in a p column.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,lipsum,longtable,colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage{dcolumn}%,tabularx,tabulary}%,threeparttable,longtable,tabu}
%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3em}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{longtable}{%
|>{\columncolor{gray}}p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
|p{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth -2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\cellcolor{gray}} A column} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{B column}\\ \hline
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\lipsum[2] & 
{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.1em}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.3\textwidth}|m{0.3\textwidth}|}\hline
A & B \\ \hline
A & B \\ \hline
A & B \\ \hline
\end{tabular}} \\
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[3] \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are there any of my packages you are not using there:-)

Comment: David -- You are Guru, I know that for sure. Still need to learn from you. Sir.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted any code I cannot help in detail, but it feel like you are looking for the `\multirow` command. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35126/combine-4-cells-in-a-table).