# Image next to longtable with pagebreak

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, longtable

I would like to create a document with Latex that would look roughly like this:

[image: sketch]

What would be the best approach? I have tried:

1. Longtable within longtable: Does not work according to answers here:
   [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481292/nesting-longtable-within-a-longtable/481313)

2. tabular within longtable: Does not page break.
3. 1 minipage for image, 1 for table: does not pagebreak

Again, I am just asking for a basic approach that would make this possible, because I am running out of ideas.
If I had a minimal working code example I would post one, but nothing so far has worked. If one of the ones I have tried so far SHOULD work, please tell me and I'll keep trying with that one.

Thank you.

Comment: it looks like a three column longtable with images in the first column

Comment: While you can't put a longtable into twocolumn or multicolumn, you can push it to one size using the [r] option.  Then it is simply a matter of overlapping an image with the start of the table, which can be done with \raisebox or tikz.